# Offset table columns in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

How can I achieve the following look with HTML and CSS?

[image]

It's basically a timeline within a table, with times below the column.

I was thinking something like the below would work (please click on the code snippet) or somehow offset the second row to the right so I can then center the text for the dates.

```css
#table1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: #555;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  height: 100%;
 }

#table1 td,
#table1 th {
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<tr>
  <td>1
  </td>
  <td>2
  </td>
  <td>3
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="1.5">1
  </td>
  <td colspan="1.5">2
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That looks like a poor use for a table. I'd rethink.

Comment: ok, how would you do it?

Comment: There are lots of good JQuery plugins to create timelines.  I've just used this one in a project: https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/  really easy to implement, but there are lots of others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct cellpadding, and cellspacing :)

```css
#table0 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#table1 td:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

#table2 {
    text-align: center;
}

.blue {
    color: blue;
}

.first{
    border-right: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<table id="table0">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="first">00:05</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="table1">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
        <col width="50"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
    <colgroup>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
        <col width="100"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>01:00 <BR> <span class="blue">03/27</span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>02:00</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>03:00</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```